# Why Does apt-get update Make HTTP Requests

Tags: apt, https

When I run `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu Server 14.04, it seems to be making a lot of requests to `http://` sources. I would expect that something as important (and dangerous!) as updates would be handled over an encrypted connection (`https://`) but it appears it isn't. Why is that?